# Stripe Payout to Bank Account

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

We are using Stripe on our MVC Web Project. I am trying to figure out how we can send money to anyone's bank account from our stripe account.

I have found this documentations but both of them are not suitable for our scenario. This documentation explains how to accept ACH payments, but we need to send not accept:
https://stripe.com/blog/accept-ach-payments

Another one explains how to send money with Stripe Connect, but in this scenario payee must have stripe account:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts

Is there anyway to directly send money to someone's bank account?

Comment: See following : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-API-for-making-ACH-deposits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are known as ["Payouts"](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-debit-card-payouts) and they require the use of [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) and Connected Accounts which have [external accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_accounts) you can pay out to.

Complete guide to paying out to a user [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide).

Answer (score 0):

but if I create multiple bank account under my profile in stripe, and then each account associate with an individual ANY other regular bank account for the payouts. I think this could be a workaround for you to transfer money from your stripe accounts to multiple regular bank accounts. Don't you think?

Comment: Can be added as comment instead